# Weblogic server BASIC Authentication not prompting for username

Tags: basic-authentication, weblogic-10.x

I created a very simple Weblogic 10.3.5 web application with BASIC Authentication that for some reason doesn't prompt for the username and password.  I believe the web.xml and weblogic.xml are created properly.  The *entire* application is below.

It consists of two files:

1. index.html -- that anyone should be able to load
2. remoteuser.jsp -- that only people in 'group' should be able to load

I added an `<auth-constraint>` for all JSPs (*.jsp), such that only users in 'group' should be able to load them.  However, when I load the url "/remoteuser.jsp", it displays "`The remote user is null`", and doesn't prompt for a username and password.  The causes the JSP to also print out `null` instead of the remote user's name.

The `<auth-method>` is, of course, set to BASIC.

I currently don't even have any groups defined in Weblogic's Security Realm, because I want to watch it fail first.

According to this Weblogic documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/security/thin_client.html#wp1037337), I believe that I'm doing everything correctly.

Do I have to modify the Weblogic Security Realm's Authentication Provider?  Or some other setting?

I *know* that I'm doing something silly, but can't see it.  Please help!

---

**SOURCE FILES**

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>JSPs</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>group</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>group</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

**weblogic.xml**

```
<weblogic-web-app>

     <security-role-assignment>
         <role-name>group</role-name>
         <principal-name>group</principal-name>
     </security-role-assignment>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

**remoteuser.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Remote User</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Only users in "group" should be able to load this page.
    </p>
    <p>
        The remote user is <%= request.getRemoteUser() %>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head><title>WebLogic Test</title></head>

<body>
    <h1>Everyone should be able to see this.<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well...it's working now, but I'm not completely sure exactly what I did to cause that.

I do know that it works when deploying the application using a Security Model of "DD Only" or "Custom Roles".

However it fails when deployed with "Custom Roles and Policies", which seems extremely confusing to me since the description on this is `Use only roles and policies that are defined in the Administration Console.`  And that is exactly where I am defining the roles and policies!!  Sigh.

Answer (score -1):

you are defining the roles and policies on the web.xml / weblogic.xml.

if u want to use custom roles and policies u can configure then from the console in the application roles n policies.

Comment: One must define users and groups within the target WLS realm, as well as declare them in web.xml.  Read all about it here:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24485/thin_client.htm#SCPRG142