# WebService makes validation on weblogic's security realm

Tags: web-services, authentication, weblogic, ws-security

i'm trying create a webservice that makes the validations using the weblogic's security realm.

I found something but didn't works on weblogic.

Someone has an example?!

thanks

Comment: No idea what you're asking - can you add more details? There are lots of examples out there for basic user authentication like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755195/weblogic-server-basic-authentication-not-prompting-for-username

Comment: humm, i'm using weblogic and there has a provider to authenticate on LDAP... so, i want that only some users can access my webservices...
I've configure the roles to groups on weblogic...
But, i want set the WS accessibility by roles.

I know configuring in the web.xml
but i would like configure using annotations...